# Error while removing row from Libgdx's table

Tags: java, arrays, libgdx, row

I want to write a board game using LibGDX and during a game I want make it possible to add or remove rows / columns on that board. First, I made some tests to prepare myself to that. Here is the code :

```
public class Test extends Game {

    Skin skin;
    Stage stage;
    Texture texture1;
    static int columns = 7;
    static int rows = 12;
    Window window2;
    Table table2;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<TextButton>> buttons;

    @Override
    public void create () {

        skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiskin.json"));
        buttons = new ArrayList<ArrayList<TextButton>>();

        for(int i = 0 ; i< rows; ++i)
        {
            buttons.add(new ArrayList<TextButton>());
            for( int k = 0; k < columns; ++k)
            {
                buttons.get(i).add(new TextButton(("ASD" + i + k), skin));
            }
        }

        texture1 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/badlogicsmall.jpg"));
        TextureRegion image = new TextureRegion(texture1);
        stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        ImageButtonStyle style = new ImageButtonStyle(skin.get(ButtonStyle.class));
        style.imageUp = new TextureRegionDrawable(image);
        ImageButton iconButton = new ImageButton(style);



        window2 = new Window("Dialog2", skin);
        window2.getTitleTable().add(new TextButton("X", skin)).height(window2.getPadTop());
        window2.setSize(300, 400);

        table2 = new Table();

        for(int i = 0 ; i< rows; ++i)
        {
            for( int k = 0; k < columns; ++k)
            {
                table2.add(buttons.get(i).get(k));
            }
            table2.row();
        }

        ScrollPane pane= new ScrollPane(table2,skin);
        pane.setScrollbarsOnTop(false);
        pane.setFadeScrollBars(false);

        window2.add(iconButton).row();
        window2.add(pane);
        stage.addActor(window2);

        iconButton.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            public void changed (ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                new Dialog("Some Dialog", skin, "dialog") {
                    protected void result (Object object) {
                        System.out.println("Chosen: " + object);
                        if((Boolean) object )
                        {
                            for(int i = 0 ; i <columns; ++i){
                                table2.getCells().removeIndex(0).getActor().remove();}  
                        }
                    }
                }.text("Are you enjoying this demo?").button("Yes", true).button("No", false).key(Keys.ENTER, true)
                    .key(Keys.ESCAPE, false).show(stage);
            }
        });

    }




    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act(Math.min(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 1 / 30f));

        stage.draw();
    }
```

As you can see here, I'm creating a standalone button and a table and fill it with buttons. Then after button clicked I want to remove first row of that table and also move rest of rows up. It works but only once (for first row), then (with second click) I got this exception :

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index can't be >= size: 70 >= 70
```

Don't know what to do and how to fix it. Hope you can help me with this.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for reply; my code looks like this now :

```
  // initialization 
    for(int i = 0 ; i< rows; ++i)
    {
        for( int k = 0; k < columns; ++k)
        {
            table2.add(new TextButton(("ASD" + i + k), skin));
        }
        table2.row();
    }

   // sample operation - remove left column
       for(int i = 0 ; i <rows; ++i){
            table2.removeActor( table2.getChildren().get(i*columns-i) );
        }   
    columns--;
```

Also, I got similar Array in logical model and want to change state of UI table based on that array. So is this approach correct or should I change something?

Answer (score 0):

Working with a table in such a way is a bit cumbersome, at least I don't know better. A quick fix for your code would be:

```
// Global field
int removedRows = 0;

// In your listener
System.out.println("Chosen: " + object);
if ((Boolean) object)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; ++i)
    {
        table2.getCells().get(i + columns * removedRows).clearActor();
    }

    removedRows++;
}
```

But if you want to remove complete rows, I would use a VerticalGroup and add each row there, so you can directly access a row and remove it from the VerticalGroup. If you use a fixed size for the buttons then it will align properly, too.

```
table2.getCells()
```

Returns an Array, this means we now operate on that Array and NOT the table2 anymore!

This means if you execute this:
    table2.getCells().removeIndex(0);
It will just remove that cell from the array. This does NOT update the table2 as a complete object, just the cells array of that table (since no copy of that array is returned)

In other words you are doing this:

```
Array<Cell> table2Cells = table2.getCells();

Cell tableCell = table2Cells.removeIndex(0);

tableCell.clearActor();
```

So you delete the cell from the table2 cell array, and then you clear the cells contents (actor in this case). But you are not updating the table to reflect the changes of the removed cell, table2 still "thinks" that the cell is there, but you deleted it.

Thus you get the index error, because the stage draws the table, and the table wants to draw a cell that no longer exists.

So if you want to create some kind of board for a game the best way would be to code your own class that provides the functionality you desire.

A workaround would be that you reset the table and fill it again:

```
int table2Rows = table2.getRows();

table2.reset();

// Omit the first row
for (int i = rows - table2Rows + 1; i < rows; ++i)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < columns; ++k)
    {
        table2.add(buttons.get(i).get(k));
    }
    table2.row();
}

table2.layout();
```

Thus the first cell will contain the first button and so on, since the table internal values are properly updated.

Comment: Thanks for replay and help. Maybe i should try with those VerticalGroups... however u think that adding / removing rows and columns would be easier with those ? Also your answer doesnt fully meet my expectations because rest elements dont change their indexes, so in that Array, i got from getCells(), element 7 still has index 7 despite there isnt any elements before. I think it could make problems when i would like to add row before. So basically what i want to achive is a "dynamic" board so that i could add/remove columns and rows.

Comment: A "table" similar to bejeweled or something like that? Then you should not use this Table class, since it is meant for UI purposes. I will update my answer shortly to add a few explanations.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is about **row()** you are using - before the first row there is no **row cell** (marked with row() method) and that's why it does not cause error but when removing the second one it does.

Compare with **table2** without any rows to test it:

```
    for(int i = 0 ; i< rows; ++i)
    {
        for( int k = 0; k < columns; ++k)
        {
            table2.add(buttons.get(i).get(k));
        }
        //table2.row(); - we don't want any rows!
    }
```

Ok we know where problem lays but it is not the solution (ok maybe some solution it is:) ). Instead of **hard removing indexes of Table cells** you should operate on Actors of table using following code:

```
    for(int i = 0 ; i <columns; ++i){
        table2.removeActor( table2.getChildren().first() );
    }
```